# Javascript - reading a file (not uploaded file,but file present in the same directory as the html file)

Tags: javascript, html

i tried a lot for this, but didnt find the answer . How can i read a file using javascript or html . I have a text file "sample.txt" and i have some information in it . It is  placed in the same folder as the html file is placed  where the html file contains the html code that deals with this file . I just want to read the information from the file and display it on some div or whatever, i mainly want to know how to read a file .

Will provide more information if necessary .

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first: JavaScript is executed on client-side. Though you have to put up an AJAX-Request to fetch the content of your file. I think jQuery's [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) seems to be the easiest way to achieve this.

For example:

```js
$('#theContentElement').load('sample.txt');
```

Comment: i am getting error MLHttpRequest cannot load file:///..... Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Your URL might be wrong. Is this file on your local file system? So like, do you want to open a file of your HDD with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a regular Ajax request without jQuery aswell to read a file.

Following uses a GET request to get data from myfile.txt and outputs it to the DIV-tag with id *output*.

```
<script>
function ajaxGet()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","myfile.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
ajaxGet();
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Ancient history, I know, but this is a great thing to have run across, although it only seems to work in Firefox. I'm working on an automated task-set-piloted-by-local-browser project, and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

You may fetch the actual file content using javascript. Here is a sample code using jquery using the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$("#YOUR_DIV_ID").load("sample.txt");
```

This will update the content of the div with the id YOUR_DIV_ID with the content of "sample.txt"